# draw polyline on roads in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I currently have a google map in my android app with user location marker on open map and when user click to a position in map a blue marker will shows(destination marker) with a polyline between user location marker and destination marker like this image:

[image: example image]

**`How can i draw this lines in roads ???`** 
 I have following code :

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    this.googleMap = googleMap;
    googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
            destinationLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            destinationLocation.setLatitude(latLng.latitude);
            destinationLocation.setLongitude(latLng.longitude);
            destinationMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("your destination").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_destination_marker)));
            Polyline line = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                    .add(new LatLng(userLocation.getLatitude(),
                            userLocation.getLongitude()), new LatLng(destinationLocation.getLatitude(),
                            destinationLocation.getLongitude())).color(Color.BLUE).width(10));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code.

https://www.journaldev.com/13373/android-google-map-drawing-route-two-points.

Hope this can help you